# Pass Character dynamically to a macro

Tags: sas, ssas

I'm trying to pass file name to a macro. The macro runs once a month, therefore,I'm trying to store the output file with a month prefix. In the current code someone has to manually provide a file name every month (Sep17_Sales, Oct17_Sales etc.). I want to automate this so that SAS generates files with the name of the month prefixed to the data file.

Macro:

```
%macro sales (outdata = , dt =);
```

Current Code

```
%Sales(Outdata = Sep17_Sales, dt = '2017-09-01');
%Sales(Outdata =Oct17_Sales, dt ='2017-10-01');
```

My approach:

```
data _null_;
current_date = today();
current_month = intnx('month', current_date, 0, "Begginning");
Name = "_Sales";
Result = put(current_month, monyy7.) || name;
run;

%Sales(Outdata=Result, dt='2017-10-01');
```

When I try to pass the parameter, it throws error.  I tried changing Result to `%Let Result` and pass a reference `&Result` to the macro but it also fails.

Any suggestion how to solve this? Thank you for all the help!!

Comment: Does the macro really require the single quotes in the value of the DT parameter? Would it work if you used double quotes instead?  Like: `%sales(outdata =Oct17_Sales, dt ="2017-10-01");` That is much easier to generate.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing there is assigning a value to a data step variable called `Result`. The name `Result` doesn't mean anything outside the context of that datastep and therefore does not *resolve* to anything when you call your macro. What you are doing instead is telling your macro that your output file should be called "Result".

You could fix that by replacing your `Result=` line with `call symput('Result',put(current_month, monyy7.) || name);`, which effectively creates a macro variable called "Result", then call your sales macro like so: ``%Sales(Outdata=&Result, dt='2017-10-01');

**OR**, you could scratch all that and simply call your macro like this:

```
%sales(outdata=%sysfunc(today(),monyy7.)_Sales, dt='2017-10-01');
```

Going further, assuming the second argument (`dt`) is always meant to be the first day of the month formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` and enclosed in single quotes (although if that is the case I see little use in specifying it as a parameter of the macro), you could make the call even more dynamic:

```
%sales(outdata=%sysfunc(today(),monyy7.)_Sales, dt=%str(%')%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),0,B),E8601DA.)%str(%'));
```

if that date can be enclosed in double quotes, this can be simplified a little as:

```
%sales(outdata=%sysfunc(today(),monyy7.)_Sales, dt="%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(today()),0,B),E8601DA.)");
```